# Honeycomb system bar

Tags: android

I'd like to get the rectangle of the "useable" area on Honeycomb, meaning the area that does not include the Navigation Bar at the bottom. Getting the Display dimensions inculdes this area, which is not what I want.

Is there a single API call to get this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I am just testing Honecomb and find that there is no usual "full screen" for the applications, as it was on previous versions of android.

One way to find the apllication screen size is by using

```
@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
 }
```

method for the custom view or SurfaceView which fills the whole application screen.